# Jquery hide and show in one line

Tags: jquery

I need to build function that show or hide element following a boolean flag.
`flag==false: hide`
`flag==true: show`
the function should contain only single line that will starts with: `$element`.

I need to complete:

```
function willItShow($element, flag){
    $element
}
```

please help me with it.
thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

Hey if it needs to be a one liner you can use an inline if like so

CODE:

```
function willItShow($element, flag){
  $element && flag === false ? $element.hide() : $element.show() ;
}
```

Explanation:

`$element && flag === false` means that if $element is defined and the flag === false it will hide the element, otherwise if flag is true or element is not defined it will try to show, there is nothing there so it will show nothing

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to the element you want to show hide.
2. On button click use [toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to show or hide

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

version added: 1.0.toggleClass( className )

```js
$("#action").click(willItShow)

function willItShow(e) {
  $("span").toggleClass("show hide")
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='show'>Shown</span>

<input type="button" id='action' value="Click ME">
```